# Cypress - counting number of elements in an array that contain a specific string

Tags: cypress

Attempting to confirm that of all the schema in the head of a page exactly 3 of them should have a specific string within them. These schemas have no tags or sub classes to differentiate themselves from each other, only the text within them. I can confirm that the text exists within any of the schema:

`cy.get('head > script[type="application/ld+json"]').should('contain', '"@type":"Product"')`

But what I need is to confirm that that string exists 3 times, something like this:

`cy.get('head > script[type="application/ld+json"]').contains('"@type":"Product"').should('have.length', 3)`

And I can't seem to find a way to get this to work since .filter, .find, .contains, etc don't filter down the way I need them to. Any suggestions? At this point it seems like I either need to import a custom library or get someone to add ids to these specific schema. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first thing to note is that [.contains()](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/contains.html#Yields) always yields a **single result**, even when many element match.

It's not very explicit in the docs, but this is what it says

> **Yields**
> .contains() yields the ***new DOM element*** it found.

If you run

```js
cy.get('head > script[type="application/ld+json"]')
  .contains('"@type":"Product"')
  .then(console.log)                    // logs an object with length: 1
```

and open up the object logged in devtools you'll see `length: 1`, but if you remove the `.contains('"@type":"Product"')` the log will show a higher length.

You can avoid this by using the jQuery `:contains()` selector

```js
cy.get('script[type="application/ld+json"]:contains("@type\": \"Product")')
  .then(console.log)                    // logs an object with length: 3
  .should('have.length', 3);
```

Note the inner parts of the search string have escape chars (`\`) for quote marks that are part of the search string.

If you want to avoid escape chars, use a bit of javascript inside a `.then()` to filter

```js
cy.get('script[type="application/ld+json"]')
  .then($els => $els.filter((index, el) => el.innerText.includes('"@type": "Product"')) )
  .then(console.log)                    // logs an object with length: 3
  .should('have.length', 3);
```